# У меня возникает exception когда пытаюсь рефлексивно создать класс

Tags: java, рефлексия

Суть задания состоит в следующем-из файла прочитать класс его метод и соотвествующий аргумент, рефлексивно вызвать метод с этим аргументом.
Мне кидает `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Human`, я затрудняюсь понять почему.
Пытаюсь получить класс через `Class chel = Human.class;` 
`Class chel = Human.class;`

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class JavaApplication5 {
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {



      List <String> list= new ArrayList<>();

       JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
       int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null,"lol");
       if (ret==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
       {
           File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
           Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
               while(in.hasNextLine()){
                    list.add(in.nextLine());}}
                    String[] array=list.toArray(new String[0]);
                       String cl = array[0];
                       String meth = array[1];
                       String argu = array[2];
                       try{

                       //Class chel=Class.forName("Human");
                      Class chel = Human.class; 

                       Method[] methodss = chel.getDeclaredMethods();

                       for(Method method:methodss)
                       {
                            System.out.println("Method name : " + method.getName()); 
                           System.out.println("Return type : " + 
                           method.getReturnType().getName());
                            Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes(); 
                            System.out.print("Parameters : "); 
                            for (Class<?> param : params)
                             System.out.print(" " + param.getName()); 
                                System.out.println();
                       }}
                       catch(Exception e){}


  }

                    }
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы приложить код?

Comment: А файл `Human.class` при этом находится в CLASSPATH?

Comment: Я приложил, взгляните пожалуйста.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я вот честно говоря, даже не знаю как это проверить, можете инструкцию оставить как это сделать,я разбираюсь с темой, но хотелось бы поскорее проблему решить,а мат. часть доучу потом, извините за нескромность)

Comment: Приложите код `Human` для полноты картины. Я так понимаю, что он обявлен в том же проекте и лежит рядом с `JavaApplication5`, если это не так, то расскажите о нем поподробнее.

Answer (score 0):

Для начало Вам нужно загрузить класс, например с помощью URLClassLoader

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class JavaApplication5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
        int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open class");
        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            try {
                File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();

                ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});

                String fileName = file.getName();
                Class cls = cl.loadClass(fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')));

                Method[] methods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();

                for (Method method : methods) {
                    System.out.println("Method name : " + method.getName());
                    System.out.println("Return type : " +
                            method.getReturnType().getName());
                    Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
                    System.out.print("Parameters : ");
                    for (Class<?> param : params) {
                        System.out.print(" " + param.getName());
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage() + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```